# Are compact sets bounded in a topological vector space?

Tags: compactness, topological-vector-spaces

If $X$ is a topological vector space and $K \subset X$ a compact set, can we say that $K$ is also bounded?

By Rudin's functional analysis any topological vector space is Haussdorf, I read that in any Haussdorf space intersection between closed and compact set is compact, is there a similar property for boundness instead?

I cannot manage to find a proof and neither to work out one.

Can you provide or point out a proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you define “bounded” in a topological vector space? If you say that $A$ is bounded if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $0$ and a number $r>0$ such that $A\subset rN$, then your statement can be proved as follows: fix an open neighborhood $N$ of $0$ consider the set $\{rN\,|\,r>0\}$. Since $\bigcup_{r>0}rN=X$, that set is an open cover of $K$. Therefore, there is a finite set $F\subset(0,\infty)$ such that $K\subset\bigcup_{r\in F}rN$. But then$$K\subset\left(\max F\right)N.$$

Comment: Rudin defines "bounded" if for every neighborhood $N$ of $0$ there's an $r>0$ such that $A \subset rN$ to be precise, your definition is actually a consequence of Rudin's definition.

Comment: By the way, in a tvs then any compact set is bounded, but not necessarily closed right?

Comment: Yes, it is closed. In any Hausdorff space, compact sets are aclosed.

Comment: I'm drifting off a bit... But if in any topological space a compact set is both closed and bounded doesn't this imply the heine borel property? And hence we would have that any topological space has finite dimension?

Comment: First of all, I didn't say “in any topological space”. I wrote about Hausdorff topological **vector** spaces. The concept of “bounded” is undefined in general topological spaces.

Comment: I forgot literally the word **vector** in my last comment. But still if in any topological **vector space** any compact subset is both bounded and closed doesn't this imply the Heine Borel property and hence the finite dimension?

Comment: No, because although, in any topological vector spaces all compact sets are closed and bounded, in general not all closed and bounded sets are compact.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can you explain why $\bigcup_{r>0} rN = X$?

Comment: This is the explanation I've came up with. I'm assuming $X$ is Hausdorff. Take any $x\in X$. Obviously, $(\frac{1}{2^n}, x)\to (0, x)$. While it's not enough in general for function to be continuous if for every sequence $a_n$ converging to $a$, $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(a)$, it is necessary. So from continuity of multiplication, $\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot x$ converges to $0$. This means, that for any neighbourhood of $0$, all points of the sequence expect for finite amount must be in arbitrary neighbourhood of $0$. This shows that equality.